# Why do we need parseInt() with a variable

Tags: javascript

See code below. My question is, why do I need to use parseInt() on bill and tipPercent for the totalCost calculation when the use actually enters in an integer already?

```
function billTotal() {
  var bill = prompt("How much was your meal?");
if (bill != parseInt(bill)) {
  alert("You need to enter an integer");
  return;
};


  var tip = prompt("How much would you like to tip?");
if (tip != parseInt(tip)) {
  alert("You need to enter a number");
  return;
}

  var tipPercent = bill * (tip / 100);
  var totalCost = parseInt(bill) + parseInt(tipPercent);
  alert("You're Meal Cost " + totalCost);
};

billTotal();
```

Comment: Actually you are taking input from prompt. So can't be 100% sure that user gonna put an integer. There might be chances they can put string too. Although as the convention prompt always take string as input.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `window.prompt` is always a string. You need to use `parseInt` if you want to work with it as an integer.

> Please note that result is a string. That means you should sometimes cast the value given by the user. For example, if his answer should be a Number, you should cast the value to Number. `var aNumber = Number(window.prompt("Type a number", ""));`

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you need `parseInt` in order to convert a user input (`prompt`) to an integer and then does arithmetic operations using this value.

As it stated more formally [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

> The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an
>   integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral
>   systems).

Your code could be refactored like below. Initially we parse the user input and provided that input is valid we proceed with the calculation.

```
function billTotal() {

    var billStr = prompt("How much was your meal?");
    var bill = parseInt(billStr,10);
    if (!bill || bill < 0) {
        alert("You entered an ivalid value for bill");
        return;
    };

    var tipStr = prompt("How much would you like to tip?");
    var tip = parseInt(tipStr,10);
    if (!tip || tip < 0) {
        alert("You entered an invalid value for tip");
        return;
    };

    var tipPercent = bill * (tip / 100);
    var totalCost = bill + tipPercent;
    alert("You're Meal Cost " + totalCost);
};

billTotal();
```